# How to add data points and labels to dynamic Google Line Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

The google line chart coded below, brings in data from a google spreadsheet via tabletop.js.  I can't seem to figure out how to make the datapoints visible or how to control the labels that I want to place under the traditional x axis and along the traditional y axis of the chart.  Any help is appreciated.

```
/* Load the data using Tabletop */
  window.onload = function() {init()};

  var publicSpreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TLLtM8DroPLEdB5_8sLNfi2_8Lq3P7CS8654LMSVNfU/edit?usp=sharing';

  function init() {
    Tabletop.init( { key: publicSpreadsheetUrl,
                     callback: showInfo,
                     simpleSheet: true } )
  };

  /* Draw the chart */
  function showInfo(data, tabletop) {

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var chart_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    chart_data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    chart_data.addColumn('number', 'Ratio');




    data.forEach(function(data){
      array = [data.Year, Number(data.Ratio)];
      chart_data.addRow(array);
      console.log(array);
    });

  /* Set the Options*/

    var options = {

    'width':900,'height':450, 

    legend: {position: 'none'},
    title: 'fancy',
    pointSize: 30,


    hAxis: {
        title: 'Does this work?',
        titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'},
        gridlines: {color: '#f3f3f3', count: 10 },          
        format: '####'
    },

    vAxis: {
        title: 'Where does this show up?',
        gridlines: {color: 'red', count: 5},
    },

    series: {0: {lineWidth: 5}}


    };



    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById("line_chart"));

    chart.draw(chart_data, options);
  }

  };
```

Comment: you're using a _Material_ line chart (`google.charts.Line`) vs. _Classic_ (`google.visualization.LineChart`) -- there are a number of options that simply don't work on _Material_, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Comment: WhiteHat, Thank you so much for clarifying that!.  I am embarrassed to say how long I have spent trying to figure this out.  Thanks again.